# Facet Wrap ggplot geom_col has different bar widths

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a graph that has bars using geom_col, with gem_point (line) to compare performance against a "benchmark."  The performance measures belong to different domains, so I used facet_wrap to visually split the domains into groups so it's easier to view.  However, because there are different numbers of measures per domain, the bar "heights"/widths are different.

```
    df = data.frame(
  measure = c("Measure A","Measure B","Measure C","Measure D","Measure E","Measure F","Measure G"),
  domain = c("Efficiency","Efficiency","Satisfaction","Satisfaction", "Satisfaction","Satisfaction","Satisfaction"),
  overall = c(56, 78, 19, 87, 45, 51, 19),
  company = c(45, 89, 18, 98, 33, 55, 4)
)

ggplot(df %>% mutate(fill = ifelse(overall > company, " Below Overall  "," Above Overall  ")), aes(measure)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y=company, fill= fill)) + geom_point(aes(y=overall, color="overall"), size=6, shape=124) + coord_flip() + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("grey3"),labels=c("Overall")) + scale_fill_manual(values=c(" Below Overall  "="lightpink2"," Above Overall  "="lightblue2")) + facet_wrap(~domain, ncol=1, scales="free_y")
```

[image]

I saw from an older question posted about calculating the number of bars per domain, and then multiplying the width by a factor.  But I can't figure out how to do that and apply it to my graph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps using `facet_grid` with `space = "free"` would be satisfactory:

```
ggplot(df %>% mutate(fill = ifelse(overall > company, " Below Overall  "," Above Overall  ")), aes(measure)) + 
  geom_col(aes(y=company, fill= fill)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=overall, color="overall"), size=6, shape=124) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("grey3"),labels=c("Overall")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(" Below Overall  "="lightpink2"," Above Overall  "="lightblue2")) + 
  facet_grid(domain~., scales="free", space = "free") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: How would you apply an argument like `nrow` inside facet_grid?

Comment: `facet_grid` does not have this argument, I would need more context to be able to provide an opinion. Perhaps ask a data specific question here on SO?

Answer (score 2):

I end up needing this quite a bit and have switched to `geom_segment()` for many of the traditional bar plots.

```
library(hrbrthemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data_frame(
  measure = c("Measure A","Measure B","Measure C","Measure D","Measure E","Measure F","Measure G"),
  domain = c("Efficiency","Efficiency","Satisfaction","Satisfaction", "Satisfaction","Satisfaction","Satisfaction"),
  overall = c(56, 78, 19, 87, 45, 51, 19),
  company = c(45, 89, 18, 98, 33, 55, 4)
) %>% 
  mutate(fill = ifelse(overall > company, " Below Overall  "," Above Overall  ")) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_segment(aes(x=company, xend=0, y=measure, yend=measure, color=fill), size=4) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=overall, y=measure, color="Overall"), size=6, shape=124, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_comma() +
  scale_color_manual(name=NULL,
                     values=c(`Overall`="grey3", " Below Overall  " = "lightpink2",
                              " Above Overall  " = "lightblue2")) +
  facet_wrap(~domain, ncol=1, scales="free_y") +
  labs(x="Measure", y=NULL) +
  theme_ipsum(grid="X")
```

[image]

Another benefit of this is no need for `coord_flip()`.

If you *really* need the thin, separate `Overall` guide, there's a way to do that, too.

**UPDATE**

Facet ordering and spacing…

```
library(hrbrthemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

data_frame(
  measure = c("Measure A","Measure B","Measure C","Measure D","Measure E","Measure F","Measure G"),
  domain = c("Efficiency","Efficiency","Satisfaction","Satisfaction", "Satisfaction","Satisfaction","Satisfaction"),
  overall = c(56, 78, 19, 87, 45, 51, 19),
  company = c(45, 89, 18, 98, 33, 55, 4)
) %>% 
  mutate(fill = ifelse(overall > company, " Below Overall  "," Above Overall  ")) %>% 
  arrange(desc(measure)) %>% 
  mutate(measure = factor(measure, levels=unique(measure))) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_segment(aes(x=company, xend=0, y=measure, yend=measure, color=fill), size=4) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=overall, y=measure, color="Overall"), size=6, shape=124, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_comma() +
  scale_color_manual(name=NULL,
                     values=c(`Overall`="grey3", " Below Overall  " = "lightpink2",
                              " Above Overall  " = "lightblue2")) +
  facet_wrap(~domain, ncol=1, scales="free_y") +
  labs(x="Measure", y=NULL) +
  theme_ipsum(grid="X") -> gg

gb <- ggplot_build(gg)
gt <- ggplot_gtable(gb)

gt$heights[[7]] <- unit(2/5, "cm") # top panel has 2 out of 5 factors vs 5 out of 5 in the bottom one

grid.newpage() ;
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution!  But the space between the bars differ depending on how many measures are in each domain.  Is there a way to make the space "even"?  Also, the facet groups are ordered alphabetically, is there a way to get them arranged a specific way?

Comment: I'm going to work on incorporating the new update, thank you.